# Add archive/category results to single post page

Tags: custom-post-type-archives, archive-template

Have posts, want related categories to display under them.

Post example: Artist name.

Category example: posts with the Artist name.

My current version, arrived at based on a comment from @birgire, adds a WP_Query block under the single.php page template. It currently returns all the posts categorized to the artist, but returns them as full posts instead of the default post thumbnail above an excerpt.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'pdsh_posts',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order'   => 'ASC',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $post->post_name,
            ),
        ),
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
        //the_excerpt();
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
    endwhile; 
?>
```

Wondering if this a good solution easily completed with css or am I missing some fundamental step?

This mockup shows what I'm going for:

[image]

Comment: Maybe this is where the "Multiple Loops Example" sections of https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop might be used...

Comment: Concatenating the string "category-" with the title "c-c-beck" to populate this line... <?php query_posts( 'category_name=category-c-c-beck' ); ?> ?

Comment: Tried just <?php query_posts( 'category_name=category-c-c-beck&posts_per_page=10' ); ?> followed by the loop from archive.php but got "Nothing Found. It seems we can’t find what you’re looking for." returned.

Comment: Dont use query_posts because of its side effects. Look into WP_Query for secondary loops. Alternative approach is using js+rest api.

Comment: Oh cool. This kinda worked... <?php 
   $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'pdsh_posts',
       'tax_query' => array(
           array(
               'taxonomy' => 'category',
               'field'    => 'slug',
               'terms'    => 'c-c-beck',
           ),
       ),
   );
   $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
   while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
   endwhile; 
  ?>

Comment: This gives me the category posts based on the current slug... 'terms'    => $post->post_name,

Comment: When I add 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC', I get all the posts in that category as full posts in alphabetical order, which is cool. I could use the_excerpt() to get only excerpts but that's not what I want. Anyway, seems it's going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. A conditional in content.php in template-parts/ checked whether the content is_archive. I assume the functionality behind is_archive is whether the file was launched from archive.php. Since it wasn't it didn't fire.

Final step was redirecting to a custom content-post-type.php in template-parts that doesn't have the is_archive check. Seems like it all works right now. Thanks to birgire for the nudge.

So my final single.php goes:

```
<?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

            the_post_navigation();

        // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
        if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
            comments_template();
        endif;

    endwhile; // End of the loop.
    ?>
        
    <!--ADD AN ARCHIVE FOR php echo $post->post_name -->
        
    <?php 
        $page_title = $wp_query->post->post_title;
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'pdsh_posts',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order'   => 'ASC',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $page_title,
                    //'terms'    => $post->post_name,//
                ),
            ),
        );
        $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
            //the_excerpt();
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-pdsh', get_post_format() );
        endwhile; 
    ?>
```

Where "pdsh_posts" is a custom post type.

Comment: Actually, this is not yet a solution. It works for existing posts but doesn't for new posts. New posts are confused about where the archives are coming from. It puts the artist post under the artist post, instead of posts about the characters associated with the artist under the artist post.

Comment: My mistake. It still seems to work. The problem lay with category slugs. Some new posts for creators had a "-2" in its slug because new categories named after the new artist did not have a special suffix in the slug to differentiate them.